# Should we merge the tags [effect-identification] and [identify-this-effect]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

We have the pair of tags [identify-this-effect](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-effect) and [effect-identification](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effect-identification) which appear to serve the same purpose. The current stats are as follows:

- 3 questions tagged with [effect-identification](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effect-identification), and
- 2 questions tagged with [identify-this-effect](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-effect).

There are no questions tagged with both, and all these questions are answered.

Since there are so few questions, I suggest that we retag these questions to preserve just one of these two tags. I recommend retaining the [identify-this-effect](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-effect) tag, since we have a large number of identification tags in the standard format `[identify-this-*]`.

What do you feel? Is it alright if I go ahead and retag the three questions tagged [effect-identification](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effect-identification)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree this is a duplicate tag and have created this synonym.